# Value not getting correlate in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to co-relate a value in Jmeter. The value to co-relate is BUVF+HUNDOK+......I have used the regular expression extractor and save the value in variable A.
When I run the script and see the result in View Result tree I can see the value is getting saved but the value I am getting for A= BUVF HUNDOK . The Jmeter is not saving the + variable in A. For + sign it is saving a space in that place. If anyone encountered the problem before,please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be due to any regex mistakes in your side.

It is perfectly working in my Jmeter check my log output: `jmeter.util.BeanShellTestElement: DU+TEST+JAX+TEST+`  and I used String **BODU+TEST+JAX+TEST+SER** with Regex **BO(.*)SER**.